# Trying to put an exception to RewriteRule in .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am redirecting all requests like so:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php?/ [QSA,L]

# the line below is the one I'm having trouble with

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !^market-reports$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php?section=$1 [QSA,L]
```

All my incoming links are meant to go to index.php, as you can see. But now I want to stop one from going there. I've never written my own `RewriteCond` before, so I'm a little unsure if what I am doing is correct.

Basically what I'm trying to say is: "If incoming URL is a file, directory or /market-reports/ do nothing. Otherwise send on the URL to index.php?section="

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: RewriteRule ^something - [L]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

So you just need to ignore http://yourdomain.com/market-reports (in addition to files/directories?). You should be fine with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/market-reports/?$
```

This will (not) match "http://yourdomain.com/market-reports" as well as "http://yourdomain.com/market-reports/" as the question mark "?", in the Perl Compatible Regular Expression vocabulary that mod_rewrite uses, makes the match optional (a wildcard) before the end of the string anchor, which is represented with the literal dollar sign  "$".

The "^" symbol acts as an anchor matching the beginning of the string and the "!" negates the match, so that any string URL that does not match the rest of the expression will be rewritten to the other specified rules.
See [mod_rewrite regex vocabulary](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/intro.html#regexvocab)