# adding exception in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My current .htaccess code is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

sends

```
requests /index.php/path/to/module/ to "index.php"
 AcceptPathInfo On
```

@`todo` This may not be effective in some cases

```
FileETag Size
```

Now, I want to integrate a script with this htaccess...  Here is what the script says..."add `exception` to execute all the index.php files inside the /cometchat directory and its sub-directories on your server."

So, how can I add the exception to execute the `Index.php` from this directory, at the same time do not hamper the existing `.htaccess code`...

Answer (score 0):

You want to put your exception before your other rules to make sure it doesn't interfere.

Something like

```
RewriteRule ^cometchat/(.+)?$ cometchat/$1 [L]
```

immediately after `RewriteEngine On`

This should execute all files in the cometchat directly normally, without imposing the other rules on them.

---

An alternative would be to use a negative pattern, [as demonstrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226364/trying-to-put-an-exception-to-rewriterule-in-htaccess).