# 301 Redirect entire site to new directory except for index.html landing page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

The wordpress site I'm working on got moved into a subdirectory therefore all the links from other sites don't work anymore. I implemented a 301 redirect with .htaccess which is great because it fixes that problem BUT the old root directory now has an `index.html` that has landing page my client absolutely wants to be seen.

So, how can I set up my `.htaccess` to redirect all traffic into the sub directory (to fix the incoming links) EXCEPT the index.html in the root directory because it has the landing page.

I don't know how htaccess works well but this is what I have right now.

```
Order deny,allow
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [OR]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com/portal/$0 [R=301,L]
```

Thanks!!

Edit for clarification: 
Right now EVERYTHING redirects from the root to the subdirectory. I want everything to redirect except for index.html in the root directory. If the user requests just the domain name (`http://example.com`) without specifying a page, I also want him/her to be served up the index.html page in the root directory.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226364/trying-to-put-an-exception-to-rewriterule-in-htaccess for a possible solution

Comment: You might want to edit your question to show how what you have done does or doesn't work as intended... you are leaving people to figure out first what is wrong, before they can embark on suggesting solutions.

Comment: My apologies. Is this more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code does what you are asking for: "if the request does not match either `index.php` or `index.html` or "/" (i.e. nothing) (and the match is not case sensitive) then serve up the alternate location"

```
Order deny,allow
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.(php|html) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ {NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://example.com/portal/$0 [R=301,L]
```

I have tested this using the excellent online testing tool http://htaccess.madewithlove.be

Using the following test cases:

```
http://example.com                -- no rewrite, second condition not met
http://example.com/               -- ditto
http://example.com/index.html     -- first condition not met
http://example.com/index.php      -- first condition not met
http://example.com/some/page.html -- rewritten as http://example.com/portal/some/page.html
```

**EDIT** You said that this still didn't work quite as expected; so I brought out the big guns. By turning on "maximum logging" of everything that the rewrite engine does with the directives

```
RewriteLog "/var/log/apache2/rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
```

(pick any path you want, obviously), then looking at the end of the logfile in a terminal window with

```
tail -f /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log
```

You can quickly see where things are not working quite right. A bit of fiddling led me to the following code. It says "if the requested URI is just `/index.html` or `/index.php`, or if it starts with `/portal`, or if it is blank, then don't redirect.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.(php|html) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/portal.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/portal$0 [R=301,L]
```

The test cases worked for me - see if they work for you!

NOTE: I made these changes in the `httpd.conf` file, not in the `.htaccess` file of the root directory. You need to be careful to make it so the `.htaccess` file in the root directory is even read - the default Apache configuration has an `Override none` for that directory, so some extra work is needed. By putting this configuration change in the `httpd.conf` file (and issuing a `sudo apachectl restart` command) you avoid the difficulty. Depending on who is hosting your website, and what control you have, that may not be an option for you.  There may come a point where the experts for this problem can be found on `superuser.com` rather than SO... but I'm hopeful this does the trick for you.

Comment: Awesome! It works if I specify exactly example.com/index.html as my address.  If I just put in example.com, then it skips the index.html and the redirect kicks in.  Is there a way for me to get around this? 

Thanks so much!

Comment: To clarify: if people request the root (with no extension), you want to redirect them to `index.html` as well - and not just when they ask for `index.html`?

Comment: just a quick update. We tried this:
`code RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.(php|html)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/portal/$1 [R=301,L] 
`
and it didn't work properly either. Still needed to have index.html specifically written.

Comment: sadly that didn't work either. :( I really appreciate the help though!

Comment: I implement the change and it is still forwarding right to /portal/ unless i specify index.html. This is very fustrating. I'm wonering if there is something in my apache config that could be doing this? I really don't know enough about the system.. :(

Comment: Strange. Its possible the test site i used didn't inderstand the directoryindex directive. What happens if you move the DirectoryIndex directive to AFTER the rewrite?