# 301 a directory URL and all of its contents to another excluding sub directory

Tags: http-status-code-301, post-redirect-get

i have a wordpress website in the directory ''  / Video/ ''  and another PHPMELODY vIDEO SCRIPT in the sub directory /Video/Play/.
in this case i would like to redirect all URLs in the directory called '' Video'' [ except ''Play/] to /Video/Play/index.html.
  I really need help, Thanks !

*********Let me make it clear********************
www.mysite.com/Video/--------- wordpress site
www.mysite.com/Video/Play/---- PhpMelody Site*

i want all URLs which are in the "Video" Folder to be redirected to either in the '' Play'' folder like this www.mysite.com/Video/Play/index.html OR to www.mysite.com/index.php.
Just EXCLUDE directory( folder) "play" from redirecting.

```
*********************

#BEGIN mod_gzip-Turn on compression
<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>
# END mod_gzip


 # BEGIN Expire cach headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
 ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expirecach  headers


 #BEGIN Cache-Control

 <ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
 </filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\\.(css)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\\.(js)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
 </filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\\.(xml|txt)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, public, must-revalidate"
 </filesMatch>
 <filesMatch "\\.(html|htm|php)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=1, private, must-revalidate"
</filesMatch>
</ifModule>
#END Cache-Control

#301 redirect URL Canonication
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ephremtube\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ephremtube.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*index\.php\ HTTP/
 RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
 # Mobile redirection
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|googlebot-  
 mobile|iemobile|ipad|iphone|ipod|opera mobile|palmos|webos" [NC]
 RewriteRule ^$ http://www.ephremtube.com/m/ [L,R=302]
 </IfModule>
 #BEGIN  pass the default character set
 # END  pass the default character set
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to put an exception to RewriteRule in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226364/trying-to-put-an-exception-to-rewriterule-in-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/Video  [NC]
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/Video/Play  [NC]
RewriteRule  ^Video/?(.*)$  /Video/Play/index.html  [R=301,L]
```

could work, if I understood your request. It will handle any URI that begins with /Video AND is not beginning with /Video/Play.

Comment: Greetings, sir, i am sure you have understood my question but it did not work 4 me, i do not know why, could you check it 4 me please, Thanks

Comment: First try simplifying the last line to `RewriteRule  . /Video/Play/index.html  [R=301,L]`. If that doesn't work, please post what your .htaccess file looks like. Are you on an Apache ("Linux") server, or Windows (IIS, Windows Server)? If the latter, you need to install a module to handle .htaccess files, or do it in a different way.

Comment: ok, i tried again and it did not work at all, and i am using Linux web server.//////my .htaccess file has contained only 2 things - #301 redirect URL Canonication  and  # Mobile redirection

Comment: Please edit your question to show your current .htaccess, and some sample inputs and what happens with them.

Comment: Hello Phil, i updated my question with the reqyue4st of .htacces file., Thanks

Comment: The Rewrite section first forces the www. version of your domain. Then it catches a request for index.php and appears to get rid of the 'index.php' part. You might try commenting out those two lines and see if it helps. For mobile agents, you are sending everything to /m/index.php (you discard any path and file) -- I suspect that's not what you want and you're missing a `(.*)` and `$1`. Finally, you do not yet have my code in for /Video and /Video/Play.

Comment: Greetings,MR Phil Perry, i used your code like the way you wanted me to do and evrything is okay now. it works for me, thank you very much !!

Comment: Hello Phill, plz i have one question if you are willig to help me ? plz