# Make folder exception mod rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, exception, mod-rewrite, directory

i was looking for rewrite rule to make an exception form rewrite rules, but nothing worked.
I want exclude folder klient from rewrite rules. I tried with

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/klient/* [NC]`

But nothing happened.... :-(
all htaccess is here

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/klient/* [NC]
RewriteRule ^index-(.*).html ./index.php?jazyk=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)-strana(.*).html ./index.php?url=$1.html&strana=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^clanek_(.*)_(.*)$  ./index.php?id_clanku=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^rssfeed.xml$   ./index.php?rssFeed=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^diskuze-([0-9]+)-[^/]+.html?$ index.php?id_diskuze=$1 [L,QSA] 
RewriteRule ^mailing_(.*)_(.*)$ ./mailing.php?sablona=$1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$    ./index.php?url=$1.html [L,QSA]
```

Is there any way to exclude my client folder?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to put an exception to RewriteRule in .htaccess](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226364/trying-to-put-an-exception-to-rewriterule-in-htaccess)

Comment: IT is similar but doesn't work for me... :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it that way

```
# leave if it is /klient/ folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/klient/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# your other rules here
```

Comment: Tanks man, it worked. Can you recommend some article please? I want kwon why is that. Thank you very much!! :-)

Comment: You can read the official Apache `mod_rewrite` documentation here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html